# Rails + Hotwire: Turbo does not trigger on links that change the subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

According to the documentation:

> By default, Turbo Drive only loads URLs with the same origin—i.e. the same protocol, domain name, and port—as the current document. A visit to any other URL falls back to a full page load.

However I would like to have Turbo work between subdomains (within the same base domain). Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you explain more about your use case? Is this something that you've done with plain Rails before?Are you just trying to send HTML responses between subdomains, or is there something else?

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround for this?

Comment: @aidan This was part of studying Hotwire, and I was trying to refactor an existing multi-subdomain application to an SPA. Now I recognize it might have been better to focus on converting each subdomain portion to a separate SPA.

Comment: @Chris No. I am not actively working with Hotwire at the moment. I will leave this question open in case someone finds a way to do this and wishes to share.

Comment: I found two workarounds: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/161